# Почему батник не прекращает работу?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Написал такой батник для вычисления длины строки:

```
set /p stroka=
set /a c=0
:vhod
if (%stroka%==) (
goto :vyhod1
) else (
goto :vhod1
)
:vhod1
set stroka=%stroka:~1%
set /a c=%c%+1
echo %c%
pause
goto :vhod
:vyhod1
echo %c%
pause
```

В шаге итерации строка уменьшается, счетчик увеличивается, все хорошо. Только вот почему-то не останавливается: после того, как переменная stroka перестает состоять из одного символа, она начинает циклически принимать значения пробела, ~1, 1. Попытка проверки в ифе совпадения значения переменной stroka с каждым из этих значений ничего не дает. Вывод с в шаге итерации я потом уберу: он не нужен, это понятно. Это пока.

Answer (score 0):

Все, нашел. Помогло [вот это.](http://scriptcoding.ru/2013/08/17/operator-if-cmd/) Вот батник:

```
@echo off
set /p stroka=
set /a c=0
:vhod
if "%stroka%"=="" (goto :vyhod1) else (goto :vhod1)
:vhod1
set stroka=%stroka:~1%
set /a c=%c%+1
goto :vhod
:vyhod1
echo %c%
pause
```

Работает в том числе и при наличии пробелов в переменной. А, интересно, этот код будет работать при наличии любого знака в переменной?